# Some users and with some web browsers can't access my website

Tags: nginx, web, server, connection, plesk

I am having a trouble with one of my company's website. Some users with some web browsers can't access my website. They get the error "Move permanently".

So I called our host provider and the advisor (not sure of the translation) told me that with Firefox on his computer he couldn't access the Website, but with another web browser he could.

Then he tested on another computer with Firefox and he successfully accessed the Website.

It is incomprehensible ...

- The server is running on debian + nginx.
- We have plesk and only this website installed on it.
- The website is secure with SSL and http is redirected to  https.
- www.exemple.com is redirect to exemple.com

Anyone has an idea ?

**EDIT 12/18/17**

With curl I have :

- 200 on https://exemple.com
- 301 on https://www.exemple.com
- 301 on http://exemple.com
- 301 on http://www.exemple.com

And for each 301 I have Location: https://exemple.com

So everything seems ok ...

The weird thing is that it concern a few people with no relation between them. Sometimes it's with Firefox, sometimes with every web browsers that he can test.

Also, i called again my host provider and i could talk again with the advisor that i had before this morning, and now with Firefox he can access the website.

I feel i'm banging my heads against a wall right now  ..

Comment: What's the website URL?

Comment: Sorry, i have a sickly paranoia of letting my website url visible on a site full of people that might have strong capacities on coding. Can i send it to you in private maybe ?

Comment: With http/https and www/non-www you have four test cases, three redirects and one website. Have you tested all three redirect cases using a tool such as `curl`?

Comment: I answered you directly in my post, for everyone can have a look at this point.